# StaX's isRepairingNamespaces feature generates a prefix different to 'xml' for the XML namespace

Tags: java, serialization, marshalling, xml-namespaces, stax

I create serialized XML as follows:

```
XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
factory.setProperty(XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, true);

StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(buffer);

writer.writeStartElement("doc");
writer.writeAttribute(javax.xml.XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI, "base", "/mydoc.xml");
writer.writeCharacters("Hello world");
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.close();

// buffer now contains:
// <doc xmlns:zdef101282835="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" zdef101282835:base="/mydoc.xml">Hello world</doc>
```

So the repairing namespace feature has generated a prefix other than `xml` for the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace.

That would be fine by me if it weren't for the errors then returned when re-parsing the document. When I try to parse the resulting document, I get the following exception:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xml" cannot be bound to any namespace other than its usual namespace; neither can the namespace for "xml" be bound to any prefix other than "xml".`

Is there a way to configure the `XMLOutputFactory` to do this correctly?

Just before you tell me to use the `writeAttribute` method that includes the `prefix`parameter, I'm channeling SAX events between objects without wanting to know what they are. That's specifically why I want the marshaller to handle namespaces for me... so I don't have to write in a specific case for one given namespace whose prefix is pre-determined. Given that the `xml` namespace doesn't even have to be defined (and probably shouldn't even be so), it would be an easy exception to write into the `IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES` codebase, wouldn't it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The writer will only "repair" namespaces that are not bound to a prefix. Adding

```
writer.setPrefix("xml", XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI);
```

before actually writing the root element fixes the problem.